# Catalyst Control Center disables dual screen on login

Tags: multiple-monitors, ati

After setting up dual screen in Catalyst, it works fine while logged in. Then if I restart, in the GNOME login screen it is still working fine. During login there's some flickering, and now dual screen is disabled! This is 100% reproducible with the Catalyst version from about a week ago.

[The lack of detail is because I won't be back at my desktop for a few days. Just hoping this is a known problem with a known solution.]

See also [this question](https://askubuntu.com/a/159686/10192)

Comment: Can you post the contents of /etc/X11/xorg.conf?

Comment: @RobinJ: No such file or directory. I think they changed the configuration drastically in one of the later Ubuntus.

Comment: That's probably the point. I think the problem is that the file is being deleted. As (if I remember correctly) ATI's control center saves your display configuration in that file (just like NVIDIA's one).

Comment: @RobinJ: Today I upgraded the driver, and after a failed boot moved the xorg.conf.fglrx-something backup to xorg.conf. The next boot was the first time it started in dual screen mode! Why didn't it work before if it made a backup of a working configuration? Anyway, I'd accept your answer if you put it as a response.

Comment: Done. And why it didn't work at first is a mystery to me as well :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the file (xorg.conf) is being deleted. As (if I remember correctly) ATI's control center saves your display configuration in that file (just like NVIDIA's one).

Comment: Restoring xorg.conf.fglrx-something to xorg.conf made this work. No idea why...