# ATI Catalyst doesn't retain changes after reboot when setting extended display

Tags: multiple-monitors, fglrx, ati, catalyst

I have Ubuntu 11.10 and I'm trying to set up extended display for my two displays.

I have an AMD 6870.

fglrx and fglrx-updates are installed.

When I launch amdcccle trough the terminal (using sudo), I select in tab "Multi-Display" the option "Multi-display Desktop with Display(s)".

Then it says for changes to be done I have to reboot my computer.

Being a good an obedient lad I do just that, but after rebooting the displays are still in the same "clone" option as before in the Catalyst Control Center and no changes are made.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After using amdcccle to set the monitors as required, apply and exit, then from **System** -> **Preferences** -> **Screen Resolution** [or **Monitors** in Debian], verify it is showing the resolution you configured in amdcccle and click apply.

The next time you restart or login the settings will be preserved.

Comment: Thanks, this is a really stupid bug still present in whatever version of fglrx is in Ubuntu 12.10. I've just been resetting the setting each time on boot which is a huge pain.

Comment: Very simple, this should be a bug and fixed in CCC. I'm guessing all this solution is doing is writing the settings created in CCC to xorg? Strange. Thanks for your guidance, very helpful.